# ASGI servers does not start the server, instead gets stuck after giving the command to start the server

Tags: django, uvicorn, daphne, asgi, hypercorn

I am trying to run an Django ASGI application, using ASGI web servers like Daphe, Uvicorn, Hypercorn on my windows machine. But, the server only starts with Hypercorn. I am not able to start the server with the other two.

The commands I gave are

1. Daphne

   ```
   daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 my_app.asgi:application
   ```
2. Hypercorn

   ```
   hypercorn -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 my_app.asgi:application
   ```
3. Uvicorn

   ```
   uvicorn -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 my_app.asgi:application
   ```

PS: I have configured the `settings.py` file to serve ASGI application, by adding

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = "my_app.asgi.application"
```

And, I do not get any errors in the logs too.

How do I go about this?